# Display the push notification ios only if it for the user saved category inside app

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I have created a shopping cart IOS app where the user can save Categories for which they are interested in (saved inside app localstorage). Now, whenever the admin is adding any product, I am sending the push notification from the server.

My question is how should i handle push notification, so that when my push notification will arrive on an ios device, it will check using APN PAYLOAD that if this product is from the user saved interested categories (saved inside app localstorage) and then display the push notification to the user, else the push notification will be ignored.

Can someone please tell me how to handle this exactly??

P.S - I am aware of the Silent Push Notifications and Push Notifications in IOS, the only problem is you can use the silent push notification for some app processing but again let's say if I send a Push Notification for an added product in cart, and when the app will receive the silent push notification and after code processing how I can again display the push notification again if the push notification is for the user interested category???

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please note that this is not a code-writing service. Try showing some of the work you have already done and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: You are not getting my question actually. I am NOT asking for ANY code. I am just asking if the "ios slient push notification" will work, because push notifications are meant to directly displaying the the content to the app, and with "silent push notification" you can do some processing, without displaying the push notification, but again how can I display the push notification again to the user after checking for interested categories??

Without understanding a question you can't downvote that!!

Comment: Simple solution: Save categories in server based on user. Send notification based on categories.  Another solution: Using silent notification send a notification to the user, if the category is matched then show the alert view(if the app is opened.) or if the app is closed or background, then process the notification in background and show the alert view while the app comes to foreground.

Comment: if you want to show the push notification again, schedule the local notification and display the notification.

Comment: Thank you RJV Kumar for your detailed response. But like I said, I would like to show it as push notification NOT like the alert box. For that I need to use Local Notification and in that case, I need to schedule it but is it not possible to show the LOCAL notification as soon as I receive Sient Push notification and process it inside the app??